# Como pegar valor selecionado de Dropdown Menu e inserir numa variável PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql-select

Tenho os seguintes menus dropdown no meu website:

```
<div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Selecione o Campo
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">

            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Codigo</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Cargo</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Tipo</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Nome</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Nome Usual</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Endereco</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Numero</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Complemento</a></li>

   </ul>
 </div>

Tipo de Busca:
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Selecione a Busca
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Comeca com</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Igual a</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Termina com</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Contem</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" >Contem as partes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6"> </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12">Buscar</button> </div>
 </div>
```

Eu preciso pegar o que o usuário selecionar nos Menus Dropdown e inserir numa variável PHP para fazer uma consulta no banco de dados por meio de um SELECT. De que maneira eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Ai meu Deus. Não sei como deixar mais específico do que isso.

Comment: Você tem que enviar uma solicitação AJAX para o back end com o valor do dropdown.

Answer (score -2):

Primeiramente eu usaria um select para pegar a escolha do usuário e colocaria dentro de um form, desta forma:

Selecione a Busca

```
<form action="/test2" method="post">
    @csrf
    <select name="select_data" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Atenção para o atributo name, que será passado com o value escolhido:

Para testar a "passagem", fiz uma rota POST que dá um dd na request:

```
Route::post('/test2', function () {
    dd(request()->all());
});
```

Como saída temos:

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "6IIS7TBpFYwRIRkDXM9N2LKsFKdaiFvhgEe2G2pV"
  "select_data" => "2"
]
```

Comment: Tá melhor que as outras respostas(1 foi apagada). Mais ainda resta a pergunta e se o AP não estiver usando o Framework Laravel?

Answer (score -4):

Não to conseguindo colocar o codigo aqui, joguei no codepen.

https://codepen.io/marcossancal/pen/yLXYYYW